# rspec route testing and hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, host, hostname

I see I can test routes with rspec like this:

```
get("/").should route_to("welcome#index")
```

but I have constraints based on the hostname or parts of hostnames and redirects between several ones. How do I specify a hostname when testing?

How do I run the tests with proper configuration? I tried printing root_url and I got:

> Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set
>   default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

Answer (score 51):

The same error happens on mine whenever I run `rspec spec/`

The entire error is actually:

```
Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
     # ./app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_confirmation_instructions_html_erb__980323237__638702928'
     # ./spec/models/campaign_spec.rb:21
```

The following line:

```
# ./app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_confirmation_instructions_html_erb__980323237__638702928'
```

actually gave me the hint that devise is the one throwing out the error.

Turns out I haven't set

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

in `config/environments/test.rb` (only in development.rb)

Adding the config option cleared out the errors on mine.
I'm suspecting you're using other gems that requires the same option set.

Comment: I'm not using devise, and I got the same error when I was trying to use something_url instead of something_path in one of my mailer views - because actionmailer doesn't have any idea what sort of environment its running in. Your solution works, but I just wanted to clarify that it is not caused by devise.

Comment: @Oranges13: 6 months after and I can clearly see that it's not devise causing the error, it's just that it passed through devise' views. I'm kind of happy I documented my whole debugging process, makes me realize how much Rails I've learned.

Comment: @Rystraum I could resolve the issue with your solution. However, assuming that your User model includes Devise's `:confirmable` module then in your factory definition for `:user` setting confirmed_at attribute in following manner `confirmed_at { Time.now }` prevents the *Missing host...* error. Nevertheless setting default host is required when our code involves generating absolute urls for the links. Thanks.

Comment: @JiggneshhGohel Thank you for adding that comment, you have saved me so much time and stress. This solved it for me when nothing else would.

Answer (score 20):

None of the above worked for me. Adding the following to my spec_helper.rb (in my case spec/support/mailer.rb which is included in spec_helper.rb) fixed the error:

`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'test.host'`

Comment: This helped me, but i had to put it in the _rails_helper.rb_ instead. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had to add

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:5000' }
```

to following to

```
config/environments/test.rb
```

because I was using FactoryGirl to generate a user without skipping the email_confirmation from user.