# How do I create a new user in Devise during my migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I had this working in an old project, but it's possible this changed in one of the more recent versions. I'm currently using Devise 2.0.4. I'm attempting to create a new user during my migration using

```
 User.create :email => '[password]',
             :password => '[password]',
             :password_confirmation => '[password]'
```

but when I do this, it aborts with the following error

```
 rake aborted!
 An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

 ActionView::Template::Error

 Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:reset => db:migrate
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Alternatively, I could create the user using the rails shell, but for consistency, I'd like to have one default user to get started every time.

Comment: Why are you not using seeds for this ?

Comment: Good question. Mainly because I remembered that there was a concept for that, but couldn't remember the name, and when searching for what I did know, seeds didn't come up.

Comment: So, if this is solved, may be you should add an answer and close the question. However, I won't mind adding an answer myself :P :)

Comment: Ya, actually I have an answer! Stupid stack overflow won't let me submit it for 6 more hours because I'm under 100 points!

Comment: There was a little more to this than just the seeds, but once I had that, the rest of it just fell into place. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [prasvin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528303/how-do-i-create-a-new-user-in-devise-during-my-migration#comment12071085_9528303), I found that the better way to do this was to go into `db/seeds.rb` and populate a seed element such as

```
 User.create(:email => '[email]', :password => '[password]', :password_confirmation => '[password]')
```

This itself lead to a different error message

```
 rake aborted!
 Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

Which I eventually found through [a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182600/rspec-route-testing-and-hosts) was related to the fact that in my `config/environments/development.rb` file I had not yet set

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000'}
```

Which means that when Devise was trying to send out the confirmation email, it failed because it didn't know what address to tell them to come back to. This is what caused the `ActionView::Template::Error`. Once that is all done, it works perfectly as expected.